# How to find $n$ of the $n$-fold rotation symmetry explicitly for a $4\times 4$ Hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, rotational-dynamics, symmetry, matrix-elements

Given a 2D crystal Hamiltonian $H(k_x,k_y)$ in terms of momenta $k_x$ and $k_y$, how do I use the [rotation operator](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bbm%3A978-1-4684-0208-7%2F1.pdf) $R_n(\theta)=e^{-i \theta \vec{J}\cdot\vec{n}}$ (or otherwise) to find the Hamiltonian's possible $n$-fold rotational symmetry.
I know that if $H(k_x,k_y)$ has $n$-fold rotational symmetry, then $R_n(\theta) H(k_x,k_y) R_n^{-1}(\theta)=H(k_x,k_y)$.
Since this is a 2D crystal, I expect this $\vec{n}$ to be in the $k_z$ direction, perpendicular to the $(k_x,k_y)$ plane.
I expect to plug in various $n$ to $\theta=2\pi/n$ in $R_n(\theta)$ to find which $n$ would work out.

[This post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/439990/) discusses this for a $2\times2 $ system, but I am lost on which matrices to use for $\vec{J}$ in $R_n(\theta)$. This is because I have a bunch of $k$-space Hamiltonians written in the basis of valence band and conduction band states, like the one below from this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.06830.pdf#page12):

[image]

I doubt I can use a general rotation matrix such as the one below that rotates about the $xy$ plane, because it is independent of $k_x$ and $k_y$:
$$
R_n(\theta)=
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos{\theta} & -\sin{\theta} & 0 & 0\\
\sin{\theta} & \cos{\theta} & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0& 1 &0 \\
0 & 0& 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Or do I use [a general expression](https://www2.ph.ed.ac.uk/%7Eldeldebb/docs/QM/lect8.pdf) for $L_z$?
$$
L_z
=
- i h (x \frac{\partial}{\partial y}-y \frac{\partial}{\partial x})
$$?

Or instead of matrices, do I simply use $R=e^{i \theta (k_x + k_y)}$?

Any suggestions or resources to help me tackle this?

Comment: What basis is $H$ in?

Comment: @SuperCiocia usually it differs from case to case; but to give a concrete example, here is a $k.p$ expansion for a 3R MoS$_2$ Hamiltonian: equation 1 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.06830.pdf

Comment: well you're gonna have to write $R$ in the same basis in order to do the prove the transformation. I don't understand that paper. So, in your own words, what basis is this specific $H$ in?

Comment: also, your $H$ is not Hermitian ... ?

Comment: @SuperCiocia Maybe that’s where my confusion lies, I’m guessing it’s not as straightforward as I thought it would be. Other than it having to be in the same basis and Hermitian, what else should it be?

Comment: Well to start with it should be hermitian otherwise it’s not a Hamiltonian. Then you’d have to ariete the rotation operator in whatever basis your H is.

Comment: @SuperCiocia, thanks. As for the example Hamiltonian in my post, I was just trying to emphasize the $k$ dependence.

Comment: I understand. But that doesn’t allow us to answer your question. What basis is your Hamiltonian in (tight-binding, plane waves, ...?) and why is it not hermitian?

Comment: @SuperCiocia I was hoping for a general answer because I am trying to understand how to do this for different Hamiltonians in different bases, but most of them are tight-binding Hamiltonians so I should have specified that. I’ll edit my question, thanks.

Comment: Actually, I think most of them end up being in the basis of valence/conduction band states.